# Лучшая практика для создания сервера - корутины или poll / select

Tags: c++, golang, сервер, coroutine, epoll

коллеги.
Некоторое время писал разное прикладное клиент-серверное ПО на C++. Моя обычная практика (в общих чертах):

1. создать "серверный" сокет для приема входящих подключений
2. тем или иным образом "отметить" его как "серверный"
3. написать фрагмент кода/функцию приема входящих подключений (1)
4. написать фрагмент кода/функцию обслуживающий принятые подключения (клиентов) (2)
5. написать фрагмент кода/функцию обслуживающий таймаут ожидания (3)
6. завести массив / вектор для файл-дескрипторов
7. запустить select / poll для этого массива
8. при наступлении какого либо события (1),(2) или (3) - дернуть соответствующую функцию.

В принципе, для не сильно нагруженных приложений всегда хватало такого подхода. Корутины C++ для этого не использовал в основном потому, что они в этом языке неудобные (мнение субъективное).
Однако прочитал я про замечательные примеры корутин в Go и, соответственно, примеры реализации клиент-серверных приложений на этих корутинах (ибо там они очень удобно выглядят). Как я понял, в общих чертах подход следующий:

1. создать "серверный" сокет для приема входящих подключений
2. написать функцию-корутину приема входящих подключений (1)
3. написать функцию-корутину обслуживающую принятые подключения (клиентов) (2)
4. на каждого из принятых клиентов заводить "свою" корутину
5. корутины "сами дергаются" при наступлении события

Пытаюсь для себя вывести соображения, какой подход лучше и почему. Первый подход, кажется, более платформозависимым, в отличие от второго. При первом подходе мне проще отслеживать состояние сокета: готовность на чтение, запись (иногда полезно знать, что сокет именно готов), отключение корреспондирующей стороны. На первый подход хорошо ложится "машина состояний".

Со вторым подходом я знаком сильно хуже, но все же. Второй подход условно более расширяемый, в том плане, что в корутины закатать можно и какие-то другие операции. Пожалуй, асинхронно удобнее писать в сокет большие объемы данных. Большего придумать не сумел.

Предлагаю высказать свои соображения по этому поводу или собственный опыт.

P.S. Если для обсуждения данного вопроса выбрал неправильную площадку, то прошу простить, а пост снести

Comment: Машина состояний это неудобно, корутины для того и изобрели, чтобы избавиться от машины состояний (точнее, компилятор всё равно генерирует машину состояний из корутины, но программисту это не видно)

Comment: В этом описании "второй" подход отличается от первого только тем, что там почему-то пропущены некоторые пункты, ничего подобного "сами дергаются" там не происходит. Еще стоит отметить, что понятие "корутины" радикально отличаются в golang и С++.

Comment: В Go есть горутины, это не тоже самое, что корутины. Так что не надо применять в go то, чего там нет.

Comment: Коллеги, предлагаю не переходить к извечному вопросу "чей язык круче и чем". Я описал крайне упрощенный вариант серверного обслуживания.  Второй подход я практически полностью переписал с примера  "кричащий сервер на go", как я его увидел и понял. В данном случае вообще  не важно что там под капотом, особенно если смотреть с верхнего уровня. Если у вас есть собственный опыт написания серверов на классическом юниксовом поллинге, корутинах или горутинах (если так принципиально), то прошу поделиться соображениями почему именно так и какие преимущества дает. За конструктивное обсуждение)

Comment: Корутины - это ни разу не альтернатива поллингу. Непонятно, почему вы их пытаетесь противопоставлять.

Comment: Первый подход эффективней, второй *потенциально* (я не случайно выделил это слово) более управляем (в смысле, когда у вас разные команды делают разные части большого серверного проекта)

Answer (score 0):

В Го, безусловно, для работы с сетью предполагается использовать только горутины. Вообще горутины - фундаментальная парадигма для асинхронных операций. Более того, в интерфейсе стандартной библиотеки в принципе нет сокетов, даже в полустандартной библиотеке [`golang.org/x/net`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net) их нет. Соответственно, нет и прямого доступа к системным вызовам
`select`/`epoll`. Нет, конечно, если очень надо, то всё это можно сделать через пакет `syscall`, но не нужно.

Идиома для обработки сетевых соединений исчерпывающе описана в примере к типу [`Listener`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listener):

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    // Listen on TCP port 2000 on all available unicast and
    // anycast IP addresses of the local system.
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        // Wait for a connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // Handle the connection in a new goroutine.
        // The loop then returns to accepting, so that
        // multiple connections may be served concurrently.
        go func(c net.Conn) {
            // Echo all incoming data.
            io.Copy(c, c)
            // Shut down the connection.
            c.Close()
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

1. Функция `net.Listen` создаёт слушателя на заданном порту.
2. Далее в цикле серверная горутина ждёт соединения в вызове `listner.Accept`. Этот вызов возвращает объет типа `net.Conn`, у которого вместо системных вызовов `send`/`recv` в наличии методы `Write` и `Read`.
3. Для обработки клиентского подключения порождается горутина с новосозданным объектом `conn` в качестве параметра. Объект `conn` реализует интерфейсы `Reader` и `Writer`, поэтому поверх него можно накрутить любой вид стандартного ввода-вывода -- `io.ReadAll`, `io.Copy`, `bufio` и т.д. и т.п. Завершаясь, горутина должна закрыть соединение.

Для незначительного ускорения процесса вы можете не порождать горутины, а использовать какой-нибудь пул (или написать его сами), но с архитектурной точки зрения разница невелика.

На самом деле глубоко в кишках рантайма таки происходит `epoll`. Реализация пакета `net` вместо того, чтобы заблокироваться на сокете в системном вызове `accept` или `recv`, регистрирует соответствующие события в `epoll` и передаёт управление планировщику. Планировщик помечает горутину как ждущую и подбирает следующую горутину для исполнения. Переключение между горутинами дёшево, планировщик Го очень старается минимизировать простои, раскидывает горутины по разным потокам (thread-ам) и разным ядрам, поэтому (ИМХО) реализация сокет-сервера на горутинах весьма эффективна. Едва ли получится переиграть планировщик ручным асинхронным вводом-выводом.

Так что ответ на ваш вопрос - только горутины.